# Issue building hello world app: Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 10.0.0

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I am trying to run a hello world react native app on my mobile.
When I typed npm start, I get following output:

```
Your phone will need to be on the same local network as this computer.
For links to install the Expo app, please visit https://expo.io.

Logs from serving your app will appear here. Press Ctrl+C at any time to stop.

 › Press a to open Android device or emulator, or i to open iOS emulator.
 › Press q to display QR code.
 › Press r to restart packager, or R to restart packager and clear cache.
 › Press d to toggle development mode. (current mode: development)

17:46:20: Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 17.0.0, 7.0.0, 8.0.0, 9.0.0
```

You can see error line above.
And when I took picture of QR code and try to connect to app from mobile, a loading is displayed continuously.
Can someone help what is wrong?

p.s. I followed [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

---

Exact commands I used:

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
npm start
```

I had to downgrade to npm version 4.6.1 though

Comment: 1) Exactly what commands did you execute? 2) Kind of obvious, but did you install the Expo app on your device and are on the same local network? If so, what error is the app showing you?

Comment: You need to `cd AwesomeProject` and run `npm start` from inside the project directory. When you do that, are you still getting the error?

Comment: @MichaelCheng I updated question with commands I used. Sure I have expo and they are on same local network. There is no error from the Expo side, just a loading bar. I can see my app in Expo, when I click it the app is being rebuild (I can see on my PC terminal - I get output similar to what is on my question). But on the expo there is just a loading icon.

Comment: @MichaelCheng Of course I did cd, I assumed that

Comment: Ok, just gotta make sure. I have literally answered a (now deleted) question in the past where that was the issue. Let's troubleshoot a bit. Are you testing on an Android or iOS device? If Android, have you tried [this suggestion of reinstalling the Expo app](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/568)?

Comment: reinstallation fixed it